# new relic developer mode transaction tracer needs more detail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

So I'm trying to fine tune this slow ass controller action with New Relic on my local host. Unfortunately, it basically tells me how long that action takes and clicking on the action name to see the corresponding line of code leads me to `route_set.rb` at the following line:

```
 result = route.app.call(env)
```

which I guess corresponds to the call of that action.

I tried to set `transaction_threshold` to a lower value and tweak other parameters in `newrelic.yml` but I can't seem to get more detail.

Am I missing something or should I consider another approach/tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to add some custom instrumentation to your app.  New Relic instruments a lot of common libraries by default (rails, active record, memcache, etc.) but you can pretty easily add tracers to other methods that are invoked in your show ass action.

Typically you'll do something like:

```
SomeClass.class_eval do
  include NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer

  add_method_tracer :slow_method_1
  add_method_tracer :slow_method_2
end
```

There's more details here: http://newrelic.com/docs/docs/custom-metric-collection

Also there's usually someone available in freenode #newrelic irc channel to help out.